# Trouble with sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, monogame

I need make client-server game with 2 players. I bind client sockets on localhost and different ports. For connection clients send serialized msg with enum header and theirs IPEndPoints as value. When server receives connection messages from different clients, they are having same ports. How to fix it?

Method which receives connections:

```
        public static void GetConnections()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections...");
            var len = ServerSocket.Receive(TempData);
            var msg = (NetMessage)DataSerializer.Deserialize(TempData);
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Data.ToString());
            if (msg.PacketType == PacketType.CONNECT)
            {
                String[] IP = msg.Data.ToString().Split(':');
                if (Player1IP == null)
                {
                    Player1IP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP[0]), Int32.Parse(IP[1]));
                    Console.WriteLine("Approved connection of player 1 with remote endpoint: " + Player1IP);
                }
                else if (Player2IP == null)
                {
                    Player2IP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP[0]), Int32.Parse(IP[1]));
                    Console.WriteLine("Approved connection of player 2 with remote endpoint: " + Player2IP);
                }
                if (Player1IP != null && Player2IP != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Both player are connected");
                    Console.WriteLine(Player1IP + " " + Player2IP);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Connection method(runs once):

```
        public void GetConnection()
    {
        NetMessage msg = new NetMessage(PacketType.CONNECT, ClientSocket.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
        var bytes = DataSerializer.Serialize(msg);
        ClientSocket.SendTo(bytes, ServerIP);
        BeganConnection = true;
    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose a problem by description alone. Could you post the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: added code to post

Comment: Did you debug or add logging to the client side, to see what they actually send? Does it match what the server receives?

Comment: I'm using monogame, for debug I set local ep string to window title before send and they are different.

Comment: The code above makes no sense to general .NET audience, as `NetMessage` and so on are not .NET Framework classes.

Comment: NetMessage it's custom class which contains packet type and value